# RegEx - Exclude zero

Tags: regex

How can I exclude the 0 input in this regex? The user should be able to enter any number... but not the zero

```
^([0-9]*|\d*\.\d{1}?\d*)$
```

Thank you.

Comment: Only `0` or any numeric value that is equal to 0 like `.0`, etc.?

Comment: Judging from the separator the OP wants floating point numbers to be parsed, ignoring mathematical zero, ie. does not want to match `0`, `0.0`, `.0`, `000` etc. Is that right?

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't explain it correctly. What I meant is that the user should not be able to enter things like 0 or 0.0 or 0.000, etc... but they user should be allowed to enter 0.1, 0.01, 0.001... 1.2, etc...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following regex

```
^(?!0*(\.0+)?$)(\d+|\d*\.\d+)$
```

Does not match

```
0
0.0
 .0
```

But allows

```
  .1
 0.01
 1.00
 1.1
01.01
10.10
 1
```

Comment: I think your solution is better than mine. But you introduced a problem. `\d{1}?` is different from `\d?`. The first one makes the `{1}` lazy (no difference ==> required one digit) and the second one the `\d` optional. So your expression accepts e.g. "1." what the OPs version would not accept. I think changing it to `^(?!0*(.0+)?$)(\d|\d*\.\d+)$` would be the solution. If you correct this error you will get my upvote and I delete my answer.

Comment: It doesn't match `01` for example

Comment: You guys are right, I've removed the `{1}` which stands for nothing and made the mistake replacing it with `?`. Fixed now and matches `01` as well.

Comment: I just tried it... it doesn't not allows things like 0.3... so it's not good for my solution... but thanks

Comment: @Dave it does match 0.3 see it here on [Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vore) +1 for this solution.

Comment: @Dave sorry, for some reason the first dot was not escaped. Fixed in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
^((?:[1-9][0-9]*)(?:\.[0-9]+)?)$
```

Match:

```
1
5
10
22
5000
1.0
10.10
123.456
```

No match:

```
0
00
007
0.0
0.000
0.50
0.01
5,432.10
1,234,567
10.
```

You could further lock it down to specific ranges, as explained here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement, use `[1-9]` in place of `[0-9]` or `\d`:

```
^([1-9]*|[1-9]*\.[1-9]{1}?[1-9]*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: ^([1-9]+).\d+$
This requires you to enter at least 1 digit from 1-9

Or ^([1-9]*).\d*$
This does not require you to enter anything but does restrict what you enter as 1-9

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the:
 * [0-9] for [1-9]
 * /d for [1-9]

Original: `^([0-9]*|\d*\.\d{1}?\d*)$`

Solution: `^([1-9]*|[1-9]*\.[1-9]{1}?[1-9]*)$`

> \d is [0-9]

Answer (score 0):

This work only with natural numbers to 5 digit and limit five 0 digit at the left (you can personalize that limit)

```
/^[0]{0,5}[1-9]\d{0,4}$/
```

match:

```
1
01 .. 000001
0100000 .. 0000010000
```

not match:

```
0
00 .. 00000
```