# How to prevent inputting 0 in an specific input through jquery and show an error div through jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to prevent inputting a value as 0 in an specific input field and show an error div on inputting 0 in the input so please it will be kindful if you pleaes guide me..!

I would like to use jquery please..!

code for the following field as :

```
 <input name="invoice_price"  class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML :-

```
<input name="invoice_price"  class="form-control">

<div id="div1" style="color:red"></div>
```

Jquery :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[name='invoice_price']").on('blur keyup',function(){
    if($(this).val()=='0')
    {
       $("#div1").html('0 value not allowed');
       $(this).val('');
    }
    else
    {
       $("#div1").html('');
    }
  });
});
```

Fiddle link :- http://jsfiddle.net/0mat1amf/1/

---

As questioner asked another question in comments section(that user can only enter maximum three digits) then i m adding more code here :

```
 <input name="invoice_price"  class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="3">
```

Comment: To be precise, his input isn't identified by `id` of invoice_price, its the name `attribute` of the element.

Comment: @Exception : Really it's very great of you..but if you can update the code to prevent people from entering other than numbers like 1234567...!

Comment: @SalmanKhan...in that situation better way is to use regular expression...instead..

Comment: @Exception : thanks you are really helping but you got it wrong please  I want to prevent users from inputting 0 and alphabets in simple..! so they will have to be able to enter only values 123456789 etc..!

Comment: @Exception : sorry for that..It was just an example to tell you as I didn't write 89 there..!

Comment: @SalmanKhan...you will make me mad...hahaha...then use regex instead..see here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910972/regex-exclude-zero

Comment: and how to assign max entering values length too please..! like I want to make people able to enter only 3 characters lenth like 123 not more than 3 characters length please..

Comment: Thanks for your time..I have selected your answer and it is solved now..! besides I worked out myself the input prevent from alphabets..!

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<input name="invoice_price"  class="form-control" 
    onblur="(this.value == 0) ? (this.value = '') : ''" />
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/v0bwvzkr/1/)

This will ensure that user cannot enter zero value. No need of showing an error!

Comment: Customer: "Oh my god, i want to enter 0.5 but my keyboard is not working"

Comment: @Kyborek There you go! Consider revoking the down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you could use if you want to stack up error messages:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[name=invoice_price]").change(function(){
   if ($(this).val()==0)
    $(this).after("<div>Error message</div>");
  });
 });
```

It will create error message right after the input element every time the input is changed and is wrong. Instead you might want to have predefined div and only change its contents like:

```
 <input name="invoice_price"  class="form-control">
 <div></div>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[name=invoice_price]").change(function(){
   if ($(this).val()==0)
    $(this).next().html("Error message");
  });
 });
```

Comment: If the answer works for you and you need nothing more, please mark the answer as accepted so that no more people will come and try to help you when you don't need their help anymore (you would be wasting their time): http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers