# Html pattern to exclude 0 as first symbol only from number input

Tags: html, regex

I have the following problem I need to exclude 0 as starting digit from number input I have the following code:

```
<input required type="number" min="1" value="1" id="number" name="number" pattern="[^0]d+">
```

but it doesn't work if the user decides to manually enter number like 01234.

Comment: "<input required type="number" min="1" value="1" id="number" name="number" pattern="[^0]d+">" is the code.

Comment: Does `"[1-9]\d+"` work any better for you? As written, this will allow any non-numerical character in the first position, I think.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/a/8911098/2403070

Answer (score 4):

To make it work change the type of the input to `text` and use `^[1-9]\d*$` as pattern

```
<input required type="text" value="1" min="1" id="number" name="number" pattern="^[1-9]\d*$">
```

this regex won't allow any number of starting zeros ('01', '001') nor any non-numeric characters ('1b') and accepts one digit number such as `1`.

example for complete working form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
       <input required type="text" value="1" min="1" id="number" name="number" pattern="^[1-9]\d*$">
       <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="number" pattern="(?!0+)\d+">
```

Explanation

```
(?!0+)  # not followed by any number of zeros (negative look-ahead)
\d+     # at least one digit (by implication the first one is different from zero)
```

Alternative

```
<input type="number" pattern="[1-9]\d*">
```

Comment: Your second option does not accept one-digit numbers.